# "is_assignable"error when using Boost 1.68 / LLVM / VS2017

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2017, llvm-clang

I receive the following build error when switching to LLVM toolset in VS2017 to build code using Boost 1.68. The code builds fine with MSVC compiler.
    1>C:\boost_1_68_0\boost/type_traits/has_trivial_move_assign.hpp(49): error : no template named 'is_assignable'; did you mean 'std::is_assignable'?
    1>C:\boost_1_68_0\boost/type_traits/intrinsics.hpp(233):  note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_HAS_TRIVIAL_MOVE_ASSIGN'

Comment: I get this on every Windows Clang configuration (even MinGW-w64): https://ci.appveyor.com/project/RubenVanBoxem/skui/builds/20372388

Comment: I can work around this (i.e. make stuff compile) by adding `std::` to the `is_assignable` the error mentions (intrinsics.hpp:233). I'm entirely unsure of the validity/impact of this fix though...

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem here may be `__clang` vs. `__clang__` to ID the compiler. Clang has different predefined macros depending on what front end is used. Because of this confusion, you boost may fail to include the header `boost/type_traits/is_assignable.hpp` which defines the `is_assignable` that you are missing.
Try this:
In 
  boost/type_traits/has_trivial_move_assign.hpp
add `|| defined(__clang__)` the line that tests for clang

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang)
#include <boost/type_traits/is_assignable.hpp>
```

to make:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang) || defined(__clang__) 
#include <boost/type_traits/is_assignable.hpp>
```

Boost should then include is_assignable.hpp and build.

Comment: awesome fix! They fixed it in boost 1.71 btw